# Error: Max redirects exceeded

Tags: redirect, max

I am using tinyreq for getting page content but i faced following error:

> Error: Max redirects exceeded. at ClientRequest.cb
>   (/var/www/html/node_project/node_modules/follow-redirects/create.js:64:15)
>   at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19) at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>   at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:191:7) at
>   HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] 
>   (_http_client.js:522:21) at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete
>   (_http_common.js:99:23) at TLSSocket.socketOnData
>   (_http_client.js:411:20) at emitOne (events.js:96:13) at
>   TLSSocket.emit (events.js:191:7) at readableAddChunk
>   (_stream_readable.js:178:18) at TLSSocket.Readable.push
>   (_stream_readable.js:136:10) at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:561:20)

Comment: Please add more info about what you did before you got the error.

Comment: This is web scraping code. Firstly read the product listing page and then redirect to every product's detail page to read the product detail. After reading some detail page this error comes.

Comment: Please add your code, in addition to the error message.

Comment: htmlScrape(listElement.reportUrl, dataToScraped, (err, detailPage) => {
 if(!err){
  detailPage.category= innerdata.title
  var obj={'category':innerdata.title, 'url': innerdata.url,'detailPageUrl':listElement.reportUrl,'content':detailPage}
  newData.push(obj);
 }else{
  console.log("Error Here=>", err)
 }
});

Comment: Please add your code to the question by editing it, not as a comment.